# What can I do if I think a Moderator is censoring me?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

I think a moderator has unfairly deleted some of my comments but left other comments in place - I think this is censorship.  What can I do about it?

And, in general, what can I do if I think a moderator is censoring my posts, comments, etc.?

Answer (score 13):

This question applies across all SE sites, so meta.SE is the place to look for answers, and here's one very good Q&A about it:

[What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges)

So the first step is to read and *be sure you understand* ***both*** answers on that question.  To emphasize the same points, step two is to read this Q&A:

[What can I do against moderators with double standards?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240494/what-can-i-do-against-moderators-with-double-standards)

The two takeaway messages you should get from those questions:

1. Try to work it out with the moderator in question.  Communicate.  Listen.  If you think a moderator is somehow "out to get you," there's a good chance that they (and other people) are trying to explain things to you and you're missing something.
2. Community mods are SE staff and have, basically, access to everything that's posted or done.  So do not try to provide just your side of the story - if you explain what's happened and provide links to what's been posted, *don't* leave things out.

*FINALLY...*

If you really think you have a valid complaint and can't possibly work it out with the moderator in question, you can email the community team via `community@stackexchange.com`

Comment: I would also add that this post is useful for new users of this site: [Newcomers: Be patient. You will get there if you follow our direction. Keep trying](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1927)